# Convert Excel Chart to Image in VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, vba, charts

I have a question about converting a chart in a excel sheet. I try the library [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) which is very powerful about importing data etc. But I haven't seen a method like chart.toImage or something.

```
Dim hssfworkbook As HSSFWorkbook = InitializeWorkbook(lblExcelPath.Text)

Dim sheet As HSSFSheet = hssfworkbook.GetSheet(txtTableName.Text)

Dim chart As HSSFChart() = HSSFChart.GetSheetCharts(sheet)
```

As you see I got the chart from the sheet but I can't export it. My Problem is also that the library should not use the excel application. I mean the installed office excel. The problem is that the diffrent version of excel could may a problem. Because of that `Microsoft.Office.Interop` library is not a solution. I found the aspose library which cost a bit. So first of all I try to search a free cost library for this little problem.

**Update:**

---

A possible solution could be convert the excel sheet in html and extract the image of the chart as a image. When i open the excel file and save it as html it works. Does anyone test a library which convert Excel to HTML and have success with converting the chart in it?

---

I hope everyone understands me, my english is bad ):

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Chart.Export method in Excel's object model. It's present and works the same in Excel 97 through Excel 2013. Syntax is like:

Chart.Export Filename, Filter

or

ActiveChart.Export "C:\users\Fred\Documents\Charts\MyExcelChart.png", "PNG"

Use "PNG" for charts, not "JPG".